# How to test with rest assured when post method performs both delete and put with payload

Tags: rest-assured, rest

I need help in writing rest assured script for below scenarios

Base_URI = http://localhost/TestManager/ServiceApi

Delete is achieved with : POST/User/{Id}/Delete call.

Put is achieved with : POST/User with payload.

Answer (score 0):

Follow basic principles in the tutorial - https://www.guru99.com/rest-assured.html

Answer (score 0):

I think there are 3 API one to create user, Update the user details and Delete the user

create a Map object of all the parameters used for crateing a user

ValidatableResponse createResposne = given().formParams(mapObject).when().post(URI).then().log().all();

extract the id from this API(using JSON path) and use the same id to delete the user or update the user

ValidatableResponse deleteResponse = given().formParams(mapObject).when().post(/User/{Id}/Delete call.).then().log().all();